# Downloading and returning a non blocking stream of data using SSH.Net

Tags: c#, streaming, sftp, ssh.net

I am using the [ssh.net library](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/) for performing SFTP operations to work with large data files (**>=500MB**)

I am having an issue with how to return the data in a non-blocking way.

The `ftpClient.DownloadFile()` method signature is ok, when writing to a file or if there's some way I can instantiate the stream, but am having problems on how to use it when I want to return a stream without blocking.

All the examples I have seen so far will be writing the download to a `Filestream`. Nothing that just returns a stream

With .Net's built-in FTP, you just use `response.GetResponseStream()`, and it streams back the data, without blocking.

The only way round to using it in a return statement was writing to a temporarity file. But this results in it being a blocking operation.

```
        var tmpFilename = "temp.dat";
        int bufferSize = 4096;
        var sourceFile = "23-04-2015.dat";

        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(tmpFilename , bufferSize, System.IO.FileOptions.DeleteOnClose))
        {
            sftpClient.DownloadFile(sourceFile, stream);
            return stream;
        }
```

I don't want it to block but to stream back the data.

I also would like to avoid creating a temporary file.

Is there an alternative implementation to make it stream back the data?

Or is there an alternative stream I can instantiate(except for `MemoryStream`), that would work with large files?

Comment: The download is over which protocol (i.e: HTTP, TCP)?

Comment: I dont get your questioning. How does TCP come in though since it's a non-application protocol....Dont think there such a thing as SFTP over HTTP.... But it's SFTP, over port 22.

Comment: I thought that you want to download first from the SFTP to your app (that could be in WPF or ASP.NET, i.e.). But the download is direct, right?

Answer (score 4):

This is old question, but I had similar issue.
If you want to get the stream directly you can write to MemoryStream.

```
SftpClient _sftpClient;
_sftpClient = new SftpClient("sftp.server.domain", "MyLoginHere", "MyPasswordHere");
Stream fileBody = new MemoryStream();
_sftpClient.DownloadFile(ftpFile.FullName, fileBody);
fileBody.Position = 0; //dont forget to set the stream position back to beginning
```

If you want to download file, you can make it in separate thread or as asynchronous call and then call the delegate:

```
_sftpClient.DownloadFile(ftpFile.FullName, fileBody, YourActionDelegateHere);
```

Comment: That may be fine for small files, but it is the least performant as you are not utilising buffering... you will get `OutOfMemoryException`s for large files.

Answer (score 0):

Many years later, I had this same issue that took longer to figure out than I'd care to admit. This was one of the top search results, so here's an actual answer: It turns out that SSH.NET does indeed expose an `SftpFileStream`, just with different methods that you might not see if you're looking for "Download". Instead of `sftpClient.DownloadFile(sourceFile, stream)`, use `sftpClient.OpenRead(sourceFile)`. That will allow you to work directly with the streamed data.