# stream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am trying to download a zip file from SFTP and unzip in the memory to process the file

I am using SSH.Net to download the file.

```
private static void processfilesfromftp(List<TSOracleMicrosDownLoadSetUp> list)
    {
        SftpClient sftp = HelperFunctions.GetClientConnection();
        if(sftp.IsConnected)
        {
            var files = sftp.ListDirectory("/");
            ZipFile zips = new ZipFile();
            string path = string.Empty;
            foreach(var file in files)
            {
                Stream unzippedEntryStream = new MemoryStream();
                path = string.Format("/{0}", file.Name);
                //byte[] arr = sftp.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName);
                var stream = new BufferedStream(sftp.OpenRead(file.FullName));
                //System.IO.TextReader textReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
                //System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();

                using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(stream))
                {
                    ZipEntry e = zip[0];
                    e.Extract(unzippedEntryStream);
                    System.IO.TextReader textReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(unzippedEntryStream);
                    string data = textReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

memorystream throw error System.InvalidOperationException exception at

**var stream = new BufferedStream(sftp.OpenRead(file.FullName));**

**Update**

It is not throwing any error, but the final output of the unzip file is empty.

[image]

[image]

Using Framework 4.5.2 and Visual studio 2017

Comment: Please provide more details on that exception: stacktrace, ...

Comment: Exceptions in debug watches don't mean anything.  The debugger is not nearly smart enough to know that it shouldn't try to display Read/WriteTimeout when a stream's CanTimeout property is false.  You know that.  The "timed out" message are a similar debugger problem, it has to give up when the watch expression takes too much time to produce a result.  Not uncommon when the data needs to come from another machine or needs to be produced by another thread that is in a debug break-state.  So this doesn't tell you anything interesting.

Comment: How to increase the timeout period. I have gone through different thread and did not get any solution for it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared the stack trace.

Comment: You can also look into 'keep alive' properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a SSH.Net question and not specific Acumatica.
It seems the problem is related to the SSH connection.

To change the timeout you can use `SshClient.ConnectionInfo.Timeout`. But you need to catch the exception and handle it gracefully.
[Here is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213828/how-do-i-decrease-the-ssh-net-timeout-when-my-ssh-client-disconnects-from-the-ss) with a similar issue.

BTW, you could use the included [Acumatica library to read the zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268547/is-there-a-way-to-open-and-read-zip-files-programmatically-uploaded-by-pxuploadd).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not writing the file from FTP to the memory stream so it's empty.

Try using the `DownloadFile` method from SSH.Net to write file content in the stream.

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46907346/7376238

```
SftpClient _sftpClient;
_sftpClient = new SftpClient("sftp.server.domain", "MyLoginHere", "MyPasswordHere");
Stream fileBody = new MemoryStream();
_sftpClient.DownloadFile(ftpFile.FullName, fileBody);
fileBody.Position = 0;
```